# How to draw Product image in pdf in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, pdf

I want to put product image in pdf for that I have created on function with name `Insertfunction` and call it from getPdf.

we have tried following code.

```
public function getPdf($orders = [])
{
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($orders as $order) {

        if ($order->getPoStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($order->getPoStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($order->getPoStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();

        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $order->getStore());

        /* Add document text and number */
        $this->drawPoInformation($page, $order);

        $this->drawAddresses($page, $order);

        $this->drawPublicComments($page, $order);

        $this->_drawHeader($page);

        /* Add body */
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);

            $this->insertImage($item, 70, 70, 205, 70);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }

        $this->insertCosts($page, $order);

        $this->insertTotals($page, $order);
        $this->drawPrivateComments($page, $order);  
        $this->insertAdditionnal($page, $order);

        if ($order->getPoStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}

public function insertImage($item, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page)
   {

   $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    try{

        $product = $this->productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($item->getProductId());


        //Draw image to PDF
        $productImage = '/catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

        $fileSystem = $om->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem'); 
        $pdfImage =$fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath("catalog/product".$product->getImage());

        $image =  \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($pdfImage);

        $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working and not able to get image in pdf